# Problems with updating a JScrollPane

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jlist, removeall

I know there are already 1000 threads out there that deal with this, but I've tried everything and nothing has worked so far. I am making a little app that lets me log work hours, so I have an array of strings that contains all of the hours that I work. I am trying to update the array, then update the JList that has the text, then update the JScrollPane that has the list on it. This way I can see the hours I added directly after I add them on a window off to the side.

I've tried `revalidate()` and `repaint()` on every object, I've tried the `removeAll()` method on the list as well as the scroll pane, and nothing seems to work! The only thing I CAN do is change the color of the border on the scrollpane!! I don't know why the layout is so easy to update but not the text on the pane!

Thanks for any help you can give! If you want to see the code, I can post it but it's a little confusing as this is just a very small part of the whole.

Comment: Read the JList API where you will find on link on `How to Use Lists` that contains a working example.

Comment: *"I've tried everything and nothing has worked so far"* Given (at least) one thing should work, it seems logical that you've not tried 'everything'. BTW - when updating the list, don't touch either the list ***or the*** scrollpane, just change the `ListModel`. Everything else will update automatically.

Comment: Thanks @AndrewThompson, I figured out how to use the DefaultListModel and its working now!

Answer (score 0):

I try to sort you out from it.

As you trying to add time string in Jlist then want to update your Jscroll pane.

I will go through simple

Just create your design view like:

```
Jpanel1(card layout)

 |
 ----> Jscrollpane1 

          |
           ------>Jpanel2

                    | 
                     --------> Your Jlist will be here on dynamic runtime
```

and you can manage panels instead of Jlist.

But here I go with list

```
 public void getUpdateOldWorkTimeList()
{
   List<String> workTimeList;
SwingWorker<Void, Void> mySwingWorker = new SwingWorker<Void, Void>()          {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {

          workTimeList=getMyTimeList();  // here you put your work time array

            Thread.sleep(100);
            return null;
        }
    };


     mySwingWorker.addPropertyChangeListener(new PropertyChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
            if (evt.getPropertyName().equals("state")) {
                if (evt.getNewValue() == SwingWorker.StateValue.DONE) {

                jPanel2.removeAll();
                jPanel2.revalidate();
                jPanel2.repaint();

                for (int i = 0; i < workTimeList.size(); i++) {
                    jPanel2.add(new ModelJList()).setVisible(true);
                    }                 
            }
        }
    });               

    jPanel3.setLayout(new model.WrapLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER, 1, 0));
    jPanel1.setBackground(new Color(0, 0, 0, 0));
    jScrollPane1.setBackground(new Color(0, 0, 0, 0));
    i

     jScrollPane1.getVerticalScrollBar().setUnitIncrement(16);
    int remainScroll=jScrollPane1.getVerticalScrollBar().getMaximum()-  jScrollPane1.getVerticalScrollBar().getModel().getExtent();
      jScrollPane1.getVerticalScrollBar().setValue(remainScroll);
      jPanel1.removeAll();
      jPanel1.add(jScrollPane1);

      jPanel1.revalidate();
      jPanel1.repaint();
```

}

**2 things must remind:**

1. **list model class: You need to implement.**(As your look n feel you want).
2. **getMyTimeList() method to array to list conversion.**

I already had implement it for chat application to add chat for sender and receiver side.

All the best